# Как создать кнопки в заголовке программы??? Windows Forms/C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Люди, кто может мне сказать, как создать пользовательские кнопки в заголовке программы. По программы типу Word: [image: Типа так.]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @aepot здесь вопрос не про ворд, а про шарп и оконные приложения. Ворд лишь для примера приведен. Можно было привести в пример еще и браузеры какие-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо выставить Border Style на None у окна и сделать свою собственную реализацию тайтлБара

Желательно это делать на WPF

Comment: Лааанн, спасибо за помощь... '_'